# How to add tables on Stack Overflow

Tags: support, markdown

I have a question on SQL which is really hard to ask without tables. I tried copying and pasting from Excel, but it didn't work. How do I paste table in Stack Overflow, so I can ask an actual question?

Comment: Just add sample data with table columns like you would display in a spreadsheet.

Comment: I tried pasting from excel and it gave me one line of numbers

Comment: I tend to use ASCII tables - use the code format button, and then use spaces to line columns up. For a spreadsheet, maybe export as CSV, use spaces instead of commas, and then tidy in the Stack Overflow editor.

Comment: Why isn't there an easy way to do it? I would assume its such a common thing!

Comment: (Bear in mind that questions about _Stack Overflow_ are not on-topic on the main board. This should really be asked on _Meta Stack Overflow_).

Comment: @FutbolFan: please add an answer! The question is not an appropriate place for an answer, since it reads like the OP knew the answer all along.

Comment: @EduardAnghelescu Replace the edited question with your sample data.

Comment: @halfer I believe he is looking to ask a SQL question, but he seems pretty new to SO, so he is having some difficulty adding a table in his post. I just added a sample format, hopefully that should help!

Comment: @FutbolFan: it was helpful, but still, answers in the answer box please. This question is about to close (we also don't recycle questions here).

Comment: @EduardAnghelescu See http://stackoverflow.com/tour and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92107/is-stack-overflow-a-forum.  SO isn't meant to be a forum :)

Comment: OK, tables of text data.  Next week it'll be 'can I include my metadata/schema', and then 'I attach my entire database' :(

Comment: use this tool, https://www.tablesgenerator.com/

Answer (score 134, accepted):

As of November 2020, [table Markdown](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356997/new-feature-table-support) is now supported on all Stack Exchange sites.

```
|      Heading 1      |     Heading 2    |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          12         |         34       |
|          99         |         42       |
```

renders as

| Heading 1 | Heading 2 |
| --- | --- |
| 12 | 34 |
| 99 | 42 |

You can escape the bar character within a cell using a backslash, like `\|`, like so:

| bar | asterisk |
| --- | --- |
| | | * |

Comment: was that just made with dashes and vertical lines?

Comment: And indenting by four spaces (or using the code button).

Comment: That seems rather primitive for such a large forum!

Comment: @Eduard, you can always raise a feature request on _Meta_ if you wish. I've been here for some years, and I've never seen anyone request it.

Comment: [Ah, it's been discussed here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73566/is-there-any-markdown-to-create-tables).

Comment: This is a good website I used to generate ASCII code table easily http://asciiflow.com/

Comment: @NgSekLong that's so cool. But how can you add text and copy it? (I could draw squares but that's it)

Comment: The **A** button, the 7 item from top left

Comment: Any way to escape `|` in a cell?

Comment: @PeterThoeny: it looks like it! See my update.

Comment: Any idea why this only works when editing this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67091851/how-to-compare-excel-file-with-javascript

Comment: @mplungjan: it looks like the title of "FileA - SheetX" was on the same line as the header row of the table, so it was not rendered as a table. Looks like the table rows need to be on their own line.

Comment: Yeah I figured out: a blank line on both sides is needed

Comment: @mplungjan: Do you mean before and after the table?

Comment: I cannot check now. Possibly

Comment: is there any tool available to automatically convert an html table into the table markdown format (I just did one manually in a text editor, but it was somewhat prone to me making typos)

Comment: @stevec: maybe [something like this](https://tableconvert.com/html-to-markdown)?

Comment: @halfer I just tested it on the table I did manually, and it worked perfectly. For reference I coped the HTML directly from the webpage. It did about 10 minutes manual work in ~10 seconds (and typo free).

Comment: Does anyone know how to specify centering of cell text? (If it's even possible...)