# Is there an easier way to generate tables in posts?

Tags: support, feature-request, formatting, tables

I have seen [a post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302471/how-to-put-tables-in-stack-overflow) on how to use table formatting inside Stack Overflow question posts. However, it seems to be really overwhelming to insert all the formatting for tables on your own by hand: once the input data entries get too long, the table columns or rows increase.

I am wondering if there is any syntax like HTML table tags, or any other intelligent way such as an online Stack Overflow table formatting tool that I can use?

Comment: I found https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables from another meta post somewhere. Possibly other "markdown table generator" sites may work.

Comment: What is your ‘‘small but complicated table’’ link supposed to be illustrating?

Comment: You could start writing a post on MSE as that has the new wysiwyg editor that does support tables as well as automatic screw-up of links: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/360033/opt-in-alpha-test-for-a-new-stacks-editor

Comment: @rene an answer on MSO or MSE would work for that but not a question. ;)

Comment: @Catija I opted-out of that whole thing after a major mishap due to me misunderstanding how that editor works. I didn't even know I could enable it here on MSO. That said, it is probably not what the OP is looking for.

Comment: @rene Yeah, understood. Actually, the test opts you in on both sites simultaneously. I have it on but I will often use a question to compose an answer because I don't like it. :D I do think they're starting to look at bugs and improvements but I don't have any sort of timeline. I think that the general feedback indicated that so much additional work was needed, it got de-prioritized. That said, Ben did show me that he's worked out how to do biblio-formatting for links again, which makes me very excited. It's a stupid bit considering what all is wrong but I like it a lot.